# Deliberate avoidance of something (noun of the verb "shun")

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that, basically should be a "noun" of a word [shun](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shun).

**Example:**

> It is not making the mistakes you should be afraid of, but _____ of making such mistakes.

**The definition** of a word should probably be something like:

> deliberate avoidance of something

Comment: How is *avoidance* or its synonyms not your answer?

Comment: .. the shunning of ... is grammatical, but doesn't sound very idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for the reply. I think I found the right word. It is merely "reluctance".

Comment: @tchrist was looking for something else. Some type of synonym, in some sort of way.

Comment: ... reluctance of ... doesn't work here in my opinion.

Comment: Reluctance isn’t even close to meaning what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'abstinence' as in, to abstain. 'Abstinence' is often used for people who consciously avoid indulging in activities such as alcohol , drugs or even sex.

Comment: In addition to abstinence, you could try refrain, or self-restraint...